# Printing list elements in order, as variables

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list like so:

```
>>> mylist=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I want to print statement in the following format.

```
>>> q=('%mylist% OR ' * len(mylist))[:].strip().rstrip('OR').strip()
```

The output of q is:

```
>>> '%mylist% OR %mylist% OR %mylist% OR %mylist% OR %mylist%'
```

But I want really do this:

```
'%a% OR %b% OR %c% OR %d% OR %e%'
```

How can I have this output?

I mean I want to do something like:

```
'%mylist[0]% OR %mylist[1]% OR %mylist[2]% OR %mylist[3]% OR %mylist%[4]'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and `join`

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> ' OR '.join(['%' + i + '%' for i in l])
'%a% OR %b% OR %c% OR %d% OR %e%'
>>> ' OR '.join('%' + i + '%' for i in l)
'%a% OR %b% OR %c% OR %d% OR %e%'
```

Comment: @PeterWood oh, thanks. Since I'm experience  a low speed internet it takes long time to fetch the doc link.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> s = ""
>>> import re
>>> for i in l:
        s += ("%"+i+"% OR ")
>>> res = re.sub(r"(.*)OR\s*$", r"\1", s)
>>> print res
%a% OR %b% OR %c% OR %d% OR %e%
```

Comment: `res = res.rstrip(' OR ')` is faster than `re.sub` and easier to understand.